# jQuery mouseenter not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this inside my $(document).ready(function()

```
$("#snext").on("mouseenter",function() {alert("mouseenter")} )  
$("#snext").on("click",function() {alert("click")} )
```

The click event (which DOES work!) is just there for debugging purposes..
What could possibly cause the mouseenter to not fire when mousing over ?!?
(no errors in the console)

snext is the id of an img tag (that shows just fine - even it's title shows when hovering!)

Please don't post an answer telling me this code works. http://jsfiddle.net/u4jB4/2/

Comment: Console shows any error?

Comment: Works for me http://jsfiddle.net/cubuzoa/XLWGb/35/ Please be sure you are not getting another js error from firebug

Comment: What does your html and css look like? Make a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/H7Xax/ its working check u have reference to library

Comment: I know it SHOULD be working - but it isn't. I'm asking what COULD be the problem

Comment: You could try to see if .hover() function works. Might lead to solution

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mRTaA/ Works perfectly!

Comment: Please show us your code/link. Works for me also.

Comment: It COULD be a syntax error. Did you copy and paste this code? It COULD be something else turning that action off. What you've posted works. Please post more code.

Comment: Set up a jsfiddle with some code that doesn't work for you

Comment: @T4NK3R: Make it break in a reproducible way. It's a little hard to debug a heisenbug.

Comment: It's deep in the belly of a massive system.. not easily isolated, sorry : (

Comment: I know it's hard (that's why I ask :) - no errors i firebug, no other events attached to the image... I'm just lost.

Comment: Which jQuery version are you using?

Comment: If it's so deep in something that you can't isolate it then you won't find an answer by posting working code and asking for speculation. Try to isolate it, maybe by removing chunks of code until you find it works, then look at what you removed.

Comment: Yes, I guess that's the only way. Sigh.. It's jQuery 1.7 BTW.

Comment: Try adding Click on first, then hover. Just for testing

Comment: Good idea. Switched them around. Click still works, mouseenter still doesn't

Comment: I said "no other events" - but I actually .hide() / .show() it in several places... but it IS visible when testing

Comment: That wasn't a good idea. Unless the first line contained a syntax error, or contained a trigger to the second action, the order is not relevant.

Comment: Well, it was something easy I hadn't thought of : )

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is due to another issue than the one mentioned by the OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it: Argh!
Having the title I mentioned, causes the element to "develop" a fancy popup-description, which at the same time replaces "my own" mouseenter.
Sorry to have wasted all you nice helpful peoples time : (